# C#, convert time from floating-point number representation to string representation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a time represented as a floating-point number (in seconds). I need a function to convert this representation to string format. Somethins like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get time from a float representation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="f">Time in a floating-point number.</param>
    /// <returns>Time in a string format.</returns>
    string GetTime(float f)
    {
        return f.ToString(); // string format is hh:mm:ss (h-hours, m-minutes, s-seconds)
    }
```

For example, 10.0 converts to 00:00:10, 67.0 converts to 00:01:07

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That will be [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx):

> Returns a `TimeSpan` that represents a specified number of seconds, where the specification is accurate to the nearest millisecond.

Comment: See Standard TimeSpan Format Strings, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee372286.aspx. (Unfortunately .NET 4.0 onwards, not before.)